# I Can´t start jetty from command line, it want´s a Main-Class manifest attribute

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jar, jetty

i´m new around here, so i will try to ask in the right way ;)

I´m doing an app on facebook, and i´m using jetty, here is the guide that i´m using : [Heroku jetty deploy guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner#deploy-your-application-to-heroku%20Herkou%20jetty%20deploy%20guide). In this guide, the way to start jetty it´s this:

```
java -jar jetty-runner.jar application.war
```

and this is exactly the same way recomended for the [jetty howto guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner):

```
java -jar jetty-runner.jar my.war
```

So i believe that until here, i´m doing everything fine. The war it´s an application that i´m developing, and the jetty runner jar i obtained through maven, here the tags of my pom.xml, extracted from the heroku guide:

```
<plugins>                       
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>copy</goal>
</goals>
<configuration> 
<artifactItems>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
<version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
<destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
</artifactItem>
</artifactItems>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

So, the reason that i´m asking here, it´s that i can´t start jetty neither from command line nor in a remote way (through a deploy on heroku). The error i get, when i execute (with master admin privileges in windows 7) `java jar jetty-runner.jar my.war`  is the following:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from jetty-runner.jar
```

And i don´t understand this, i´m using the jar downloaded through maven, it´s supose to work in the right way, right?

I open the manifest of the jetty-runer.jar and it doesnt have a Main-class attribute, so? what should i do? I believe that i´m doing something really stupid because i can´t find this error anywhere, but i don´t know what :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a different version. I have an old one (7.5.4.v20111024), and it does have the Main-Class attribute in the manifest, and works as expected at the command line.

The latest version, 8.1.14.v20131031 also has the Main-Class attribute.

Comment: You are right, i chose a version of jetty-runner without the main-class attribute in manifest. I tried with the latest version available and it works.

Answer (score 12):

Latest versions of jetty-runner in maven central seem to miss Main-Class attribute in jar manifest for some reason. However you can run it manually specifying main class:

```
java -cp jetty-runner.jar org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner application.war
```

Comment: The approach worked for me, thanks! The command I had to use was `java -cp jetty-runner.jar org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner application.war`. That was Jetty Runner 8.1.16 (latest at the time of writing).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for this question.
I was having the same problem trying to deploy the war file with jetty-runner on Heroku.
The pom.xml setting that Heroku suggests doesn't seem to pull the jetty-runner.jar with the main class attribute and increasing the version number didn't work either.

However, downloading the latest version of jetty-runner from [maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mortbay.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-runner%22) directly and running it as `java -jar jettty-runner.jar myapp.war` worked for me.